# gganimate with changing scales (axis limits)

Tags: r, axes, gganimate

I'd like to create a gif using `gganimate`, but my axis ranges vary wildly in one frame. This is causing all subsequent frames to be squeezed.

In `ggplot2`'s facets, there's an option to have `scales="free"`. Is there a way to have free scales in each frame of `gganimate`?

Here's an example:

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
theme_set(theme_bw())

p <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent,
                           frame = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10()

gganimate(p)
```

[image]

Now we move one of the data points to some extreme value. This squeezes the points in *all subsequent unaffected* frames.

```
gapminder[1, "lifeExp"] <- 1000
gapminder[1, "gdpPercap"] <- 1e60

p <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent, 
                           frame = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10()

gganimate(p)  # smooshed
```

[image]

Comment: So you think it would be useful to have the scales calculated individually at every timestep? I don't see how that would be helpful.

Comment: I disagree. It would be useful for my application. Much like the facet_wrap() parameter scale="free" in ggplot2

Comment: But the animation would jump around every frame.

Comment: Only if the scale changed dramatically every frame. In my application only a single frame has a vastly different scale similar to the example here.

Comment: It's also useful for timeseries, for example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UatUDnFmNTY

Answer (score 10):

You can try experimenting with `view_follow()`.

[image: 1]

#### Code

```
p <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'GDP per capita', y = 'life expectancy') +
    transition_time(year) +
    view_follow()

animate(p)
```

Comment: I would suggest to replace view_follow() with view_zoom(). It produces nicer results for time series data.

Answer (score 2):

To manually define the scales see `view_step` and `view_step_manual` (also `view_zoom` and `view_zoom_manual`).